# Need Help. How to start .net programming

Tags: .net

I have completed C, C++ and java (object oriented) in previous year. Now, I want to learn .net .But when I am looking for some youtube tutorials, it shows only .net with c#. And also I want to ask how to start journey of .net . If you know any online tutorials, then it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, what you're seeing is what you should be looking for!  C# is one of the two main languages that you can use for .NET programming, and given your background, I think you'd find it more natural to transition into C# than into VB.NET anyway.

When you come across .NET code online, you'll find it in one of those two languages -- and often, both.  The few developers I know who do prefer VB.NET to C# are mostly those who transitioned from VBScript in classic ASP web-development.  Most of the other developers I know prefer C# -- and while I don't personally have issues with either one of them, .NET with C# is really a good place to begin.

Comment: Thanks. It would be helpful for me.

Comment: Really, further to this -- take a look at MSDN, that's the main online resource for learning about the language.  And if you have any one of the flavours of Visual Studio, you'll find them very helpful when learning the language.